# Regenerate package-lock.json file?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, node-modules

I am updating a `React app` from `Node 14 to 16`. As a part of the upgrade I deleted the node_modules folder and package lock and regenerated a fresh `package-lock.json` file. It’s giving me all sorts of compilation errors with `Typescript`. If I keep the existing `package-lock.json` the Node upgrade goes smooth.

**The question is in which scenarios should you regenerate a fresh package-lock file?**

The more I read about it, it sounds like we should not manually delete and regenerate package lock file, unless there is a good reason..which I am not sure of.

Comment: what compilation errors are you getting? Can you please post the same?

Answer (score 1):

You should update package-lock.json when adding, removing, upgrading, or downgrading any package, or when fixing problems reported by `npm audit`. The lockfile is to ensure consistent node_modules across machines (mainly your CI/CD pipeline) when your dependencies haven't changed. It's not there to make your life difficult at development time.

package-lock.json also *will* automatically change when doing any of the above operations, you don't need to do anything manually. It's meant to be used by `npm ci`. Even plain old `npm i` will change your lockfile, unless you have exact versions in `package.json` and none of your dependencies' dependencies were changed at all.

Comment: Ok, I noticed the package-lock is automatically updated/auto merged as you pointed out. But is there a good reason to manually delete the package lock file and regenerate? That is where it’s giving me issues.

Comment: Theoretically there's no need to ever delete it, because npm should know what it's doing. In practice, there have been some versions of `npm` that didn't seem to know what they were doing, causing package-lock.json to not update dependency graphs correctly, but I personally haven't run into that in a long while. Unless you have issues _without_ having deleted and re-generated the file, I would not delete it. One other possible exception is if you've updated `npm` to a new major version and they changed module flattening/deduplication, which did happen several versions ago.

Comment: Good point, that is one of change I am making. Going from npm version 6 to 8, but I need to look if any of the defuplication logic has changed between the 2 versions.